# ListFilesInFolderActivity gives empty result

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using Google Play Services SDK to integrate Google Drive.

My application need to show a list of all files in a folder.

From the demos: [ListFilesInFolderActivity](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesInFolderActivity.java)

I get the folder properly without any Authorization errors etc.. Because I changed the

> com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FOLDER_ID
>   com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FILE_ID

values as per my application folder and file etc.

But in the

```
final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataResult = new
        ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
            return;
        }
        mResultsAdapter.clear();
        mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
        showMessage("Successfully listed files.");
    }
};
```

I only see the Toast `"Successfully listed files."` but nothing in the List. When checked for `mResultsAdapter.getCount()` it returns **0**.

But the folder definitely has 1 file. What am I missing?

**EDIT :**

When I created folders/files from my application, they are visible. But folders/files added from web etc.. are not visible in the List.

Is it something like:

> Only folders/files created by your application are accessible?
>
> using
>   `folder.listChildren(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallbackmetadataResult);`

Answer (score 1):

The Android API uses Drive.File scope, which means your app will only be able to see the files that the user has explicitly authorized your app to access.  (Users much prefer this scope, since they have more control over who can see what data.)

If you open items with the same app on the web, they should be accessible to your Android app, but there may be some small delay in the showing up in the list response.

Comment: In the github sample codes [Here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-querying/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/querying/HomeActivity.java) Line no 46: **Application is only authorized to query the files it has opened or created.** So, no way to query/access files created by other apps?

Comment: You can do so if the user explicitly authorizes you to access that file by opening it with your app.